# Instantiate a CacheManager bean in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache, ehcache-3

I am using

```
@Service
public class Service{
@Autowired  
private CacheManager cacheManager;
}
```

I included org.ehcache:ehcache and spring-boot-starter-cache  library in the build.gradle file.
on running the application I am getting the error:
`Field cacheManager required a bean of type org.springframework.cache.CacheManager that could not be found.`
I am not sure how to go about resolving this error

**My Thoughts:**
Looks like I need to declare a class annotated with @Configuration and with methods @Bean which returns an object of type CacheManager. I am using EhCache here. Not sure exactly how to do this.

Comment: try to add `@EnableCaching` on `@Configuration` class

Answer (score 0):

I believe [@dey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3703819/dey) is correct.

I suspect the problem you are having is that you have not explicitly enabled caching using Spring Framework's `@EnableCaching` annotation ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)).

Even with Spring Boot's *auto-configuration*, and specifically when using **Ehcache** as a caching provider in Spring Framework's Cache Abstraction, **you still need to explicitly enable caching**, as [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching).

**Ehcache** is a [supported caching provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider) (as well as [in the core Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration)) and Spring Boot does offer *auto-configuration* logic for this provider (via the JCache API). However, when using Spring Boot, an explicit `CacheManager` bean declaration (for *Ehcache*) in your application configuration is **not** required, only the `@EnableCaching` annotation is required (so long as both *Ehcache* and `spring-boot-starter-cache` are on your application classpath, as you have indicated):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class MySpringBootApplicationConfiguration {

  // your application managed bean declarations here

}
```

An explicit `CacheManager` bean is required only when 1) you are not using Spring Boot, or 2) Spring does not (provide) support the provider as a caching provider in Spring's Cache Abstraction, in which case you would need to implement Spring's `Cache and` CacheManager` SPI yourself, for the unsupported (OOTB) provider.